# How to build a custom MongoRepository with a query findByClassLiteral

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to build a `MongoRepository`that allows to find a document based on a class member.

Here is my abbreviated data object:

```
public class Example<T extends SomeType> {

  private String id;

  private Class<T> dataClass;

}
```

Here is my repository:

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends MongoRepository<Example<? extends SomeType>, String> {

  <T extends SomeType> Example<T> findByDataClass(Class<T> dataClass);
}
```

Here is an example of how I would save an instance of `Example`:

```
@Autowired
private ExampleRepository examples;

void someMethod() {
 examples.save(new Example<>(null, SomeConcreteType.class));
}
```

When I try to start my application, I get an exception:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Class.
```

I don't know if this relevant, but I am using Fongo to build an inmemory database locally.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show a sample document which is stored in your database

Comment: I don't yet have any document in my database.

Comment: ok before quering, how do you intend to save. do cou have that piece of code?

Comment: I've updated my question to show how I would save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve. If you try to save, you will get the same error message.

```
Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Class
```

This is because, Mongo doesn't know about this data type. Have a look at this link for data types supported by Mongo.
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/documents/

Comment: Thanks, can you give me any pointers on how I add support for class literals to my mongo repository?

Comment: One way could be to store fully qualified classname(with package) as string